# org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not insert:

Tags: hibernate, postgresql

Hi Im running example using hibernate with postgresql 8.4, when i try to add it will dispay following error

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not insert: [com.claystone.db.OrWorkgroup]
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2267)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2660)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:250)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:106)
    at com.claystone.server.setup.VehicleManager.AddWorkGroup(VehicleManager.java:700)
    at com.claystone.server.setup.SetupServiceImpl.AddWorkGroup(SetupServiceImpl.java:1077)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:527)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:166)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.doPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:86)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:205)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "last_modified_time" is of type last_modified_time but expression is of type bytea
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1548)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1316)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:191)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:452)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:351)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:305)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.NonBatchingBatcher.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatcher.java:23)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2247)
    ... 38 more
```

How to solve this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of the property (field) that you have mapped to the column 'last_modified_time' is not allowed for the type of the column. Either change the type of the column or the type of the property (field).

Answer (score 1):

Check the context.xml file within `$TOMCAT_HOME/conf/`, you might have a datasources conflict if one is declared several times.

You can display the list of resource names by typing:

```
$ egrep -i 'Resource[[:space:]]+name' /var/lib/tomcat6/conf/context.xml | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/name=//g' | sed 's/"//g'
```

Indeed it can happen you've been working a few weeks or months ago on an old project for which you gave the same datasource name.

Other possible explanation: you might have a jar library conflict (upon mysql-connector-java for instance ), so check $TOMCAT_HOME/lib/ and deployed applications lib/ subfolders like $TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/YOUR_APPLICATION/WEB-INF/lib/.

Hope it helps !

Pascal Ramboz (PERF IT company).

Answer (score 1):

Hi please check you cfg file, if you have 'create' in 'hbm2ddl.auto' change it to 'update'; it might be a problem

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

check the annotation on class @table(name=""),change the table name from existing one